# JqPlot highlighter misplaced on bar charts

Tags: javascript, jqplot, bar-chart

As you can see from the picture, when i hover over a bar, the highlighting tooltip and dot show up over the bar in the middle. I'm just curious if anyone has this problem, and if there is any way to make the tooltip show over the mouse or over the bar that is hovered over instead.

I've tried a workaround in highlighter.js where i tracked the mouse position. That worked only for the tooltip. The coloured dot is still misplaced.

[image: Bar chart hightlight problem]

Comment: You can overwritte highlight event using jqplotDataHighlight :

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was reported and solved by Bruno Harbulot in the issues section of the source code repository for jqPlot here: https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/514/the-highlighter-point-is-always-on-the.

Bruno's patch has not been incorporated into the jqPlot distribution, so you will have to apply it yourself to your copy of jqPlot.